# How to check if RecyclerView item exists without knowing its position, but data, using Espresso

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-testing

I have *CardView* with *RecyclerView* child. Every item in *RecyclerView* is a word with its translation. I want to test deletion of particular item in *RecyclerView*. It is important for me to be independent on position of item, because I test in different conditions (with zero, or plenty of items with possibility of different sorting... position doesn't make sense for me). Therefore I wrote *Matcher* to find view based on data in *ViewHolder*.

```
public static Matcher<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> withWordAndTranslation(String word, String translation) {
checkNotNull(word);
checkNotNull(translation);
return new BoundedMatcher<RecyclerView.ViewHolder, WordsViewHolder>(WordsViewHolder.class) {
  @Override
  protected boolean matchesSafely(WordsViewHolder holder) {
    return holder.wordTxt.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(word)
        && holder.translationTxt.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(translation);
  }

  @Override
  public void describeTo(Description description) {
    description.appendText("view holder with word, translation: " + word + ", " + translation);
  }
};
}
```

So far, so good. Assuming an item with "test_word" and "test_translation" in its *TextViews* is added to *RecyclerView*, I get appropriate view and use click action on it:

```
   onView(allOf(withId(R.id.wordsRecyclerView), withParent(withId(R.id.cardView)), isDisplayed()))
    .perform(actionOnHolderItem(withWordAndTranslation("test_word", "test_translation"), click()));
```

FYI it gives this item selection. I click delete button which job is to delete selected item:

```
onView(allOf(withId(R.id.action_delete), isDisplayed())).perform(click());
```

and I really want to check if item ("test_word, test_translation) still exists on RecyclerView. But I dunno how. Any ideas/solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Espresso documentation recommends that you [get the Adapter and iterate over it.](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso/recipes.html#asserting-data-item-not-in-adapter)
Take the example code and replace AdapterView with RecyclerView.

Comment: Yeah, but RecyclerView is not an AdapterView. It is a ViewGroup.

Comment: You're right, In my answer I mixed things up. You need to get the RecyclerView Adapter and not the AdapterView (which isn't related to RecyclerViews). The Adapter (or your child implementation of the RecyclerView#Adapter class) is the only instance which knows about all items in your RecyclerView. So you need to get the list of data from your Adapter and then verify that your item is not in this list anymore.